# Sent mails go to spam on Gmail but not on Yahoo

Tags: spam, spf, dkim

Why is a message like the following going to Gmails SPAM folder? 
I noticed that the same message goes correctly to Yahoo!s Inbox, but observing the header i see (in the received Yahoo message the following part: domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=mydomain.com; dkim=permerror (no key))

The following is the received gmail message.

```
Delivered-To: recipient@gmail.com
Received: by 10.58.136.2 with SMTP id pw2csp417955veb;
        Mon, 12 Nov 2012 08:56:07 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.180.8.134 with SMTP id r6mr11575409wia.19.1352739366833;
        Mon, 12 Nov 2012 08:56:06 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <www-data@mydomain.com>
Received: from reco-server.mydomain.com ([1.2.3.4])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id i6si8062286wix.3.2012.11.12.08.56.06;
        Mon, 12 Nov 2012 08:56:06 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of www-data@mydomain.com designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) client-ip=1.2.3.4;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of www-data@mydomain.com designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=www-data@mydomain.com
Received: by reco-server.mydomain.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 35A9FC35AC; Mon, 12 Nov 2012 18:53:38 +0200 (EET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=mydomain.com;
    s=default.private; t=1352739218;
    bh=xB6AkthEgELFO1uSJiG0uEqE+qEnyoQ/RQnK9N0kGcY=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:Message-ID:MIME-Version:
     Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type;
    b=HbafDiTnuJMT837tf/PWk0LZPMBStf17PJYM94StSg5odjEIPzuzf5hPxJc2DfQMV
     +e9MdhgDoKJ09YJJV0nvH07Y+20XB6uPOxk/sJry3ItYCFkqzbFFnK7YkAHRwIuSiy
     gueYz6tpfZekxpWTWysic465o4mRLxTG28EdnF2U=
To: recipient@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?zpXOu867zrfOvc65zrrOrA==?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:class.phpmailer.php
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 18:53:38 +0200
From: noreply@mydomain.com
Message-ID: <8002c9e1cccf93e64ea3b98588ae7971@localhost>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer [version 1.73]
X-Mailer: phplist v2.10.19
X-MessageID: 13
X-ListMember: recipient@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

MESSAGE TEXT
```

**EDIT**
Results from autmated check@isnotspam.com

```
This message is an automatic response from isNOTspam's authentication verifier service.  The service allows email senders to perform a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms.  It is provided free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community.  While it is not officially supported, we  welcome any feedback you may have at <adminemail@isnotspam.com>.

Thank you for using isNOTspam.

The isNOTspam team

==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================

SPF Check : pass
Sender-ID Check : neutral
DomainKeys Check : neutral
DKIM Check : invalid
SpamAssassin Check : ham (non-spam)
==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname: [1.2.3.4]
Source IP: 1.2.3.4
mail-from: noreply@domain.com
---------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=noreply@domain.com DNS record(s):
domain.com.     86400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 a mx -all" ""


----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: neutral
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=noreply@domain.com DNS record(s):
domain.com.     86400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 a mx -all" ""


----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=noreply@domain.com Selector= domain= DomainKeys DNS Record=

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: invalid
ID(s) verified: header.From=noreply@domain.com Selector= domain= DomainKeys DNS Record=._domainkey.

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.2.5 (2008-06-10)

Result: ham (non-spam) (05.1points, 10.0 required)

    pts rule name              description
    ---- ---------------------- -------------------------------


    *  1.8 SUBJ_ALL_CAPS Subject is all capitals
    * -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
    *  3.2 RCVD_ILLEGAL_IP Received: contains illegal IP address
    *  0.0 DKIM_SIGNED Domain Keys Identified Mail: message has a signature
    *  0.1 RDNS_NONE Delivered to trusted network by a host with no rDNS

To learn more about the terms used in the SpamAssassin report, please search
here: <a href="http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/">http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/</a>

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (adapted from
draft-kucherawy-sender-auth-header-04.txt):
==========================================================

"pass"
        the message passed the authentication test.

"fail"
        the message failed the authentication test.

"softfail"
        the message failed the authentication test, and the authentication
        method has either an explicit or implicit policy which doesn't require
        successful authentication of all messages from that domain.

"neutral"
        the authentication method completed without errors, but was unable
        to reach either a positive or a negative result about the message.

"temperror"
        a temporary (recoverable) error occurred attempting to authenticate
        the sender; either the process couldn't be completed locally, or
        there was a temporary failure retrieving data required for the
        authentication.  A later retry may produce a more final result.

"permerror"
        a permanent (unrecoverable) error occurred attempting to
        authenticate the sender; either the process couldn't be completed
        locally, or there was a permanent failure retrieving data required
        for the authentication.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

From www-data@domain.com Mon Nov 12 12:38:18 2012
Return-path: <www-data@domain.com>
Envelope-to: check@isnotspam.com
Delivery-date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 12:38:18 -0600
Received: from [1.2.3.4] (helo=reco-server.domain.com)
    by s15387396.onlinehome-server.com with esmtp (Exim 4.71)
    (envelope-from <www-data@domain.com>)
    id 1TXytm-0006Ks-F4
    for check@isnotspam.com; Mon, 12 Nov 2012 12:38:18 -0600
Received: by reco-server.domain.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 6BF85C35AD; Mon, 12 Nov 2012 20:35:48 +0200 (EET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=domain.com;
    s=default.private; t=1352745348;
    bh=ct/pgfefCHs8+LIeEBcMrJ5P+x8P9h/ezEkaBkHvCN4=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:Message-ID:MIME-Version:
     Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type;
    b=KqwYkomSJ7DFGIYp9fwajqCAPr8bab5Blp8FlbN9MGaaNIAt4pBBlnlLOeKeqQ1Dk
     B9GzgDaYmzvCeufDu6vHsDX4l2RjzvMvEOu1zYedOni71Pcm8E1R30ACmRE21GMTh1
     ydht7n4dCV1ixaRch+yA+usEExUbrrMG5kvSoZyE=
To: check@isnotspam.com
Subject: TEST FOR SPAM
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:class.phpmailer.php
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 20:35:48 +0200
From: noreply@domain.com
Message-ID: <0a2dfc42198ab976374beeb033478102@localhost>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer [version 1.73]
X-Mailer: phplist v2.10.19
X-MessageID: 14
X-ListMember: check@isnotspam.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-DKIM-Status: invalid (pubkey_unavailable)

This is a test
```

--
powered by phpList, www.phplist.com --

Comment: First check if everything is fine with your mail server by sending an email to check@isnotspam.com. Paste the result logs here then we can help you further.

Answer (score 4):

Because gmail has a different (and generally regarded as "better") spam filter than Yahoo! does.  Different spam filters behave differently.

[Gmail also has guidelines and a help page for bulk senders](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126), which will probably be much more helpful to you than us, so I recommend you check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was hidden very deep in the configuration files of dkim-milter.

This "mean" config problem caused the signer to not function(properly) resulting in a mail which is not DKIM-signed.
Details:
i 'm using Debian, postfix & dkim-milter. The problem i had was the following line in /etc/dkim-keys.conf

```
*@domain.com:domain.com:/etc/dkim/keys/domain.com/default.private
```

The last part ( .private ) MUST BE REMOVED!!

Comment: That can't be your only problem. Massive numbers of unsigned emails are accepted by Gmail every hour. If signing the message "solves" your issue then I suggest your messages are still so close to being flagged as spam that you should look at the many other issues involved because just a small change of wording might be enough to tip them over the edge again.

Comment: I have the same issue... If our solution works, I will award you 50 rep bounty! Coz u will f... deserve it! Lemme check

Comment: Nope... Didn't work!